# Let users create / list their own restaurant menu

Tags: 7, nodes

I am building a site where a restaurants visitors could register. Now, I have created a content type where the restaurant owners could list up there restaurant. I have to also allow them to add there restaurant menu based on categories like 'starters', 'mains' etc.

Is there any module which could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure what you're looking for. I'm going to assume that you're looking for a particular form to create a restaurant menu from the backend.

Drupal allows you to create this functionality OOTB (out of the box):

- Fields (formerly cck pre Drupal 7)
- User Roles
- User Permissions

You're probably going to need to output this in a pretty fashion so your best bet are some standard contrib modules:

- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)
- [Fields Collections](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)

Nonethless, these modules are standard fare for every Drupal project (except maybe Fields Collections).

Oh i googled and there are possibly similar questions out there on SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204936/restaurant-menu-drupal-7
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935899/best-drupal-gui-for-displaying-a-tiered-restaurant-menu
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835562/drupal-content-type-restaurant-design

Comment: hi, well I want the restaurant owners to register there restaurant then also create menu's which they are offering in there restaurant. Clear enough? if not please do ask me.

Comment: Alright great. Sounds like i've provided what you're looking for.

Comment: yes.. you did :)